# How to find total number of nodes in a Distributed hash table

Tags: networking, nodes, p2p, dht

How to find total number of nodes in a Distributed hash table in efficient way?

Comment: I guess you would treat it as a graph. How do you calculate the nodes of a graph? I guess something like breadth first search will work here  too.

Answer (score 2):

You generally do that by estimating from a small sample of the network as enumerating all nodes of a large network is prohibitively expensive for most use-cases. And would still be inaccurate due to NAT anyway. So you have to consider that you are sampling the *reachable* nodes.

Assuming that nodes are randomly distributed throughout the keyspace and you have some sort of distance metric in your DHT (e.g. XOR metric in Kademlia's case) you can find the median of the distances of a sample and than calculate the keyspace size divided by the average distance between nodes times.
If you use the median you may have to compensate by some factor due to the skewedness of the distribution. but my statistics are rusty, maybe someone else can chip in on that

The result will be very noisy, so you'll want to keep enough samples around for averaging. Together with the skewed distribution and the fact that everything happens at an exponential scale (twiddle one bit to the left and the population estimate suddenly doubles or halves).

I would also suggest to only base estimates on outgoing queries that you control, not on incoming traffic, as incoming traffic may be biased by some implementation details.

Another, crude way to get rough estimates is simply extrapolating from your routing table structure, assuming it scales with the network size.

Depending on your statistics prowess you might either want to do some of the following: scientific papers describing the network, steal code from existing implementations that already do estimation or do simulations over broad ranges of population sizes - simply fitting a few million random node addresses into ram and doing some calculations on them shouldn't be too difficult.
Maybe also talk to developers of existing implementations.